# WordPress: How to show product term's description in Front-End (WooCommerce Plugin)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

In WooCommerce plugin of WordPress, as you know there is one taxonomy called "Attributes" that let us add some filters (attributes) for products and assign them to products. Each attributes can have multiple items like a category with multiple sub-categories that called "Attribute terms". When we want add or edit attribute terms, we have a "Description" textarea. I have WoodMart theme so I would like to display these descriptions in Front-End in their own pages.

the URL of attribute's page in front-end is like this: `example.com/product-category/sofas/?filter_brand=4mariani`

And this is code I'm using but doesn't add nothing to these pages:

```
function display_attribute_term_description() {
    // Get the current attribute term
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // Check if the term exists and has a description
    if ($term && !empty($term->description)) {
        echo '<div class="attribute-description">' . wpautop($term->description) . '</div>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'display_attribute_term_description');
```

I'm also trying to make a category page with Elementor Plugin, but there isn't any dynamic widget for term's description. so i've added a text widget and tried to inject term's description into it and still doesn't work:

```
function inject_term_description_into_archive_description( $content ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $term_description = term_description();
        $content = $term_description . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_description', 'inject_term_description_into_archive_description' );
```

After this way, I've tried to add a custom widget in Elementor for showing term's description and still doesn't work.

```
<?php
use Elementor\Widget_Base;

class Custom_Term_Description_Widget extends Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'custom-term-description-widget';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'Custom Term Description', 'your-text-domain' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-text-area';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'section_content',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'your-text-domain' ),
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'term_description',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Term Description', 'your-text-domain' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::WYSIWYG,
                'dynamic' => [
                    'active' => true,
                    'categories' => [
                        \Elementor\Modules\DynamicTags\Module::POST_META_CATEGORY,
                    ],
                    'default' => \Elementor\Modules\DynamicTags\ACF\Module::TEXT_CATEGORY,
                ],
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();
    }

    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        echo wpautop( $settings['term_description'] );
    }

}
```

and then i just added this to my `functions.php` child-theme file.

```
function register_custom_term_description_widget() {
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/custom-term-description-widget.php';
    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new Custom_Term_Description_Widget() );
}
add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', 'register_custom_term_description_widget' );
```

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: **WooCommerce product attributes** are really very different that WordPress categories or WooCommerce product categories… **Each product attribute is a custom taxonomy** *(not hierarchical)* that has terms *(like WordPress tags)*, and they can be used to define the product variations of a variable product… For info, **the real product attribute archive link** working with the `queried_object` is built as follows `$site_url.'/'.$taxonomy_slug.'/'.$term_slug.'/'`, and doesn't work with multiple terms (as the description is based on the term, not on the taxonomy)…